# Saved WiFi passwords on Android 10

Tags: wifi-password

I'm trying to figure out the logic of the WifiConfigStore.xml file on Android 10.

I am rooted. I have a XML file generated by Titanium Backup, which I can import and have several hundreds of saved networks restored.
Each marked with "Saved by Titanium Backup".

If I remove TiB - all saved networks are gone.

Password viewers work, but I'm looking for a way to "mimic" TiB's behavior: export a list, then import it, without a specific app dependency (so passwords won't disappear if I remove the app).

I tried dumping the WifiConfigStore.xml after saving one network, manually adding a saved network, pushing it back and setting the permissions+owner. After a reboot - no saved passwords on my device.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: For adding new Wifi configurations Android has an API for ages. See WifiConfiguration/WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder. Therefore from inside an app it is plain and simple.

Comment: I'm not a developer, just a user, with some more-than-average understanding...